# How to sort the range of duplicated data in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a list of values:

```
2016-01-04T16-01-56,7
2016-01-04T16-01-57,0
2016-01-04T16-02-49,7
2016-01-04T16-03-15,7
2016-01-04T16-03-42,28
2016-01-04T16-04-37,28
2016-01-04T16-05-03,0
2016-01-04T16-05-28,0
2016-01-04T16-06-21,0
2016-01-04T16-06-46,0
```

As a result I would like to get:

```
Entries1:
BEGIN: 2016-01-04T16-01-56,7
END: 2016-01-04T16-01-56,7
Entries2:
BEGIN: 2016-01-04T16-02-49,7
END: 2016-01-04T16-03-15,7
Entries3:
BEGIN: 2016-01-04T16-03-42,28
END: 2016-01-04T16-04-37,28
```

Does anyone know about the simpliest way to achieve this?

NOTE: The 0 values are out of interest, only everything that > 0

At the moment I have a script that puts all the entries in array and scans each item in array. That way is very slow, since there are a lot of "if" statements.

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: what is the algorithm for parsing BEGIN and END?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do but this might solve your problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

entry=1
for file in "$@"; do
    prev=''
    while read -r -s line; do
        num="${line##*,}"
        if [[ "$num" != "0" && "$prev" == "" ]]; then
            prev=$line
        elif [[ "$num" != "0" || "$prev" != "" ]]; then
            if [[ "$num" == "0" ]]; then
                line=$prev
            fi
            echo "Entries${entry}"
            echo "BEGIN: $prev"
            echo "END: $line"
            entry=$((entry + 1))
            prev=''
        fi
    done < $file
done
```

Produces the following output:

```
Entries1
BEGIN: 2016-01-04T16-01-56,7
END: 2016-01-04T16-01-56,7
Entries2
BEGIN: 2016-01-04T16-02-49,7
END: 2016-01-04T16-03-15,7
Entries3
BEGIN: 2016-01-04T16-03-42,28
END: 2016-01-04T16-04-37,28
```

If this isn't what you're looking for please clarify the rules you're expecting to follow.

Comment: Hi Julian, That looks pretty much I need, but seems like it gives the correct result if there are only 2 duplicated values. But in my case the values can repeat multiply times. and in such case the result is not as I'm looking for. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please update your question to include the case you're talking about, I believe my answer is correct for the test data provided.